# isomorphisms between dice rolls

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I recently realized that 2d6 is isomorphic to 1d36.

We can see this because of the following:

Taking d1 to be the result of the first d6 roll, and d2 to be the result of the second d6 roll, then
6*(d1-1)+d2 will take the 2d6 to give the result in 1d36.

Then taking d36 to be the result of a d36 roll we see that the set {Ceiling[d36/6] , Mod[d36 - 1, 6] + 1} can give us the results of our 2d6, or just Ceiling[d63/6] + Mod[d36 - 1, 6] + 1 get the sum result of our 2d6.

Is it true in general that adb is isomorphic to xdy iff a<sup>b</sup>=y<sup>x</sup>?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might want to explain the notation with the "d" and what mathematical structure is defined on dice rolls that it makes sense to talk of isomorphisms.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. 1d6 would mean a single roll of a 6 sided die, a 2d6 would be 2 rolls of a 6 sided die.

Comment: you're using some terrible notation, di both meaning dice and toss. please edit using mathjax. the questions are intended to be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch $a$ and $b$ in the formula, then it is true.

Casting $x$ perfect dice with $y$ sides each gives a total of $y^x$ possible outcomes (assuming you can distinguish between the dice). All of those outcomes have the same probability. Now if $b^a = y^x$, throwing $a$ perfect dice with $b$ sides each gives the same number of possible outcomes. Again, all have the same probability. Now choose any bijection between the sets of outcomes. This is automatically an isomorphism of discrete probability spaces (not of groups).

Comment: Whoops, I did make a typo. Thank you for the answer, that's what I was thinking, but wasn't sure if I was making a mistake in my reasoning.